# Regedit change path windows update bat file

Tags: regedit

So i'm preparing some desktop for the clients of my job, and i need to turn off the update windows 10 so i need to change the path of it and i need to creat a bat file to change it the path is:

->\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv

I tried this but wont work -> REG ADD \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv /v ImagePath /d %systemroot%\system32\svchost.exeXX -k netsvcs /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /f

I'm totally new at this so i would appreciate your help.